# SQL must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql

I have a SQL statement

```
    sql = """
    insert into metadata (code, code_map, has_property) (
        select
            code,
            jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(new_code)) as code_map,
            has_property
        from data_to_data
        where code is not null
        group by 1
    ) on conflict (code) do update
    set code_map = excluded.code_map;
    """
```

Previously the has_property field didn't exist and this was working fine. Now that I've added has_property, I am getting the error

```
column "data_to_data.has_property" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I understand what this means, but I'm not sure how to fix the issue. The has_property field should be the same for any equivalent codes being inserted, so I'd just want to aggregate them into one Boolean.

Here is an example of the data

```
code, code_map, has_property
1, 2, True
1, 3, True
5, 6, False
5, 7, False
```

Any suggestion on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the codes are the same, there is no harm in including it in the `group by`:

```
select code,
       jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(new_code)) as code_map,
       has_property
from data_to_data
where code is not null
group by code, has_property;
```

Alternatively, use an aggregation function:

```
select code,
       jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(new_code)) as code_map,
       bool_or(has_property) as has_property
from data_to_data
where code is not null
group by code;
```

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer. In postgresql I had to use bool_or instead of max for the aggregation function. Thank you!